# VBA excel Replace

Tags: vba, excel, replace

Hi i'm the beginner in VBA 
i need to do some things but i don't have idea how to do it.

1) First I must convert comma (,) to dot (.)

2) in the Columns 2 I wanna number before the dot

3)  If in the cells is a letter I wanna  change it to number +1

for example cells (i,13) 0.b1= 0 + 1 = 1 or 3.c = 3+ 1 = 4

Below I upload example file and my code (which doesn't work)
Error: Statment invalid outside Type block.

http://www.wyslij-plik.pl/pokaz/906005---kgkx.html

[image: Excel view]

```
Sub change()

Dim i As Integer
Dim dot As String


i = 2
While Cells(i, 1) <> ""

dot = Cells(i, 1)
dot = Replace(dot, ",", ".")

 If InStr(Cells(i, 1), ".") Then
 Cells(i, 2) = Left(Cells(i, 1), 2) ' i wanna only the number before the dot

End If

If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1)) = False Then
Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i, 1) + 1

End If
  'If in the cells is a letter  i wanna  change it to number +1
for example cells (i,13) 0.b1= 0 + 1 = 1 or 3.c = 3+ 1 = 4

i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: your request are not that clear, can you add a sample of the Excel sheet before, and the result you want to achieve (just 1-2 rows) and write the data manually

Comment: yes but it my first day here now i looking how to upload excel sheet ,could you help me?

Comment: Also, instead of just "doesn't work" give more details on what doesn't work, what you get , and what you expect to get https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You can't upload files here, just images

Comment: You get the specific compiler error you mention because you need `Dim` in front of `i As Integer` and `dot As String`. The compiler error you haven't gotten to yet is that `IsNumeric` is a function.  It should be `If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1)) Then`. Fix that, then take a crack at the rest.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
Sub change()    
    Dim i As Integer, s As String, a() As String, cell As Range

    Set cell = [A2]
    While cell > "" 
        s = Replace(cell, ",", ".")
        a = Split(s, ".")
        i = a(0)
        If UBound(a) > 0 Then
            If a(1) Like "[a-zA-Z]*" Then i = i + 1
        End If
        cell(, 2) = i      ' the cell on its right
        Set cell = cell(2) ' the cell below it
    Wend    
End Sub
```

You can solve that without VBA by copying column A to column B, then Data > Text to Columns > check Comma and Other: `.`, and after that you can use this formula in `D2`:

```
= B2 + Not( IsNumber( C2 ) )
```

Comment: If UBound(a) > 0  It's everythink ok ?  becouse i  have syntax error

Comment: fixed `If UBound(a) > 0 Then`

Comment: I'm a little off topic here because I just learned something from your answer that I'd like to confirm: `[A2]` is the same as `Range("A2")` and `cell(2)` is the same as `cell.Offset(1,0)`. Is that it? Because that's amazing

Comment: @VictorMoraes more like [`Application.Evaluate("A2")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) and `cell.Cells(2, 1)`

Comment: Once again, that's amazing. I shall research about it. Thank you very much for this

Comment: Hi,its me again the sub is working but if i have Value 0A.2 or 2B.0 in cells(1,1) then get info :Run time error , Type mismatch  do you have any idea how to repair that?